# Cost of OpenGL state (VB, IB, Texture) changes?

Tags: opengl

Where can I see list of opengl commands like glBindXXX sorted by execution cost.

For example that list must gives the answer on questions:
What is more cost: change a texture or a shader?
What is more cost: change a shader or a vertexbuffer?
etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @datenwolf wrote, it's highly dependent on implementation/hardware, but here's a link to a presentation from 2014 that has a table of relative costs in decreasing order (page 48):
http://www.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/beyond-porting

Render target > Program > ROP > Texture binding > Vertex format > UBO > Vertex bindings > Uniform updates

Comment: The slides as a pdf file: www.ozone3d.net/dl/201401/NVIDIA_OpenGL_beyond_porting.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> Where can I see list of opengl commands like glBindXXX sorted by execution cost.

Nowhere, because such a list doesn't exist. OpenGL is just a specification and every implementation may behave completely different compared to every other implementation.

And the costs of state changes depend entirely on the actual implementation. That being said there are a few rules of thumb:

Operations that cool down caches are the most expensive ones to carry out. So switching a texture (and then use it for actual drawing) is quite costly; just binding a different texture and the binding another one with out doing anything with the texture however may be cheap or not.

Note that some OpenGL implementations (notably the proprietary AMD and NVidia ones) even go as far as collecting statistics and runtime profiles of the process calling into them to apply heuristics to optimize the runtime behavior.

Comment: Maybe officially such a list doesn't exist but is some lists that users make by experiment. For example I saw such a list for direct3D.

Comment: We obviously may to say that switch shader has more cost than switch blend state. I don't wanna the exact list, I wanna the approximative list.

Comment: @Vorotnyak_Nazar "switch shader has more cost than switch blend state" not necessarily, some GPUs need a new shader when you switch blend state (the blend state is compiled into the shader).

Comment: @ratchet freak,  not necessarily but on such list I can orientate.

Comment: Current list: 
Shaders,
Textures,
Vertex Buffer,
Index Buffer,
other